# VBA/Macro suddenly stopped working correctly

Tags: excel, vba, file, macros, rename

I am having a weird problem. Everything was working properly until i used another raw data file and named it as `Raw Data_Park Sampling.xlsx`. After running my code, there is no error but nothing was being copied anymore to "Random Sample" sheet.

What's weird is that the new raw data file has the same content as the previous one.

I tried to replace the data inside the previous working file and it still worked. I do not know why my code will only work if i use that specific raw data file. Why is that? Even i renamed other file with: `Raw Data_Park Sampling.xlsx` and have the same content/format it is not working.

I already tried creating another excel file and pasted the codes but still no luck. I really have no idea why this kind of thing is even happening. What is wrong?

Below is my whole code:

```
Sub MAINx1()


'Delete current random sample

Sheets("Random Sample").Select
Cells.Select
Range("C14").Activate
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp


'copy header

 Windows("Raw Data_Park Sampling.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A1:L1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Park Sampling Tool.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste



    Dim rawDataWs As Worksheet, randomSampleWs As Worksheet
    Dim map, i As Long, n As Long, c As Long, rand, col
    Dim keyArr, nRowsArr
    Dim rng As Range


    Set rawDataWs = Workbooks("Raw Data_Park Sampling.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set randomSampleWs = Workbooks("Park Sampling Tool.xlsm").Worksheets("Random Sample")
    randomSampleWs.UsedRange.ClearContents


     Set rng = rawDataWs.Range("A2:A" & _
                    rawDataWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

    Set map = RowMap(rng)

     keyArr = Array("AU", "FJ", "NC", "NZ", "SG12", "ID", "PH26", "PH24", "TH", "ZA", "JP", "MY", "PH", "SG", "VN") '<== keywords

     nRowsArr = Array(4, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2) '<== # of random rows



    Debug.Print "Key", "#", "Row#"
    For i = LBound(keyArr) To UBound(keyArr)
        If map.exists(keyArr(i)) Then

            Set col = map(keyArr(i))
            n = nRowsArr(i)

            For c = 1 To n
                'select a random member of the collection
                rand = Application.Evaluate("RANDBETWEEN(1," & col.Count & ")")
                Debug.Print keyArr(i), rand, col(rand)
                rawDataWs.Rows(col(rand)).Copy _
                     randomSampleWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                col.Remove rand 'remove the "used" row
                If col.Count = 0 Then
                    If c < n Then Debug.Print "Not enough rows for " & keyArr(i)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next c

        Else
            Debug.Print "No rows for " & keyArr(i)
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox "Random Sample: Per Day Successfully Generated!"


End Sub

'get a map of rows as a dictionary where each value is a collection of row numbers
Function RowMap(rng As Range) As Object
    Dim dict, c As Range, k
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        k = Trim(c.value)
        If Len(k) > 0 Then
            If Not dict.exists(k) Then dict.Add k, New Collection
            dict(k).Add c.Row
        End If
    Next c
    Set RowMap = dict
End Function
```

Comment: Why don't you open the workbook in your code and set a reference to it that way, much simpler and means the name doesn't have any effect on the code

Comment: im quite new to vba and don't have much idea on how to do your suggestion. can you edit my code based on your suggestion? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the workbooks within your code and set the reference that way instead:

```
Sub MAINx1()

Dim rawDataWB       As Excel.Workbook
Dim randomSampleWB  As Excel.Workbook
Dim rawDataWS       As Excel.Worksheet
Dim randomSampleWS  As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rd              As String
Dim rs              As String

MsgBox "Select the raw data workbook", vbInformation
rd = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")

MsgBox "Select the random sample workbook", vbInformation
rs = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")

If UCase$(rd) <> "FALSE" And UCase$(rs) <> "FALSE" Then
    Set rawDataWB = Workbooks.Open(rd)
    Set randomSampleWB = Workbooks.Open(rs)
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

Set rawDataWS = rawDataWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set randomSampleWS = randomSampleWB.Sheets("Random Sample")

'// Delete current random sample
randomSampleWS.ClearContents

'// Copy header
randomSampleWS.Range("A1:L1").Value = rawDataWS.Range("A1:L1").Value

    Dim map, i As Long, n As Long, c As Long, rand, col
    Dim keyArr, nRowsArr
    Dim rng As Range

'// rest of your code here ...

End Sub
```

Comment: i don't understand why i need to select rawdata workbook and then select random sample workbook. I am running the code in the workbook that has Random Sample Worksheet where the random rows from rawdata workbook should be pasted

Comment: I created another workbook but still, nothing was being copied but the header only

Answer (score -1):

Macros will not work in xlsx file, save it in xlsm.

Comment: i got xlsm file. it is where my macro is. "Park Sampling Tool.xlsm". I am just getting random rows from "Raw Data_Park Sampling.xlsx".

Comment: Also, i tried saving "Raw Data_Park Sampling.xlsx" as "Raw Data_Park Sampling.xlsm" but still no luck. Still not working